# Uniform choice of start position and end position for lines between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am drawing a figure which has many nodes and many lines connecting the nodes.
I want every line connecting two nodes to start from "north" and to end to "south". So, essentially, my code is something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (a) at (0,0) {};
 \node (b) at (0,1) {};
 \draw (a.north) -- (b.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with many nodes definitions and many draws. 
I want to define once and for all that all line should start from "north" and end to "south", so I tried something like

```
 every path/.style={parent anchor=north, child anchor=south}
```

but it doesn't work.
The question is:
is there a way to specify in the template that any line should start from "north" and end to "south" so avoiding the need to write this in every draw?

Comment: Why not using `\draw (a) -- (b);`?

Comment: You could use a loop to draw the lines, `\foreach \i/\j in {a/b, c/d, e/f} {\draw (\i.north) -- (\j.south);}`, is that an option?

Comment: @percusse If the nodes aren't at the same x-coordinate, that won't work. (I assumed that's the case here, even if the example doesn't show it.)

Comment: @percusse: I chose  a bad example, my mistake: I have many nodes and they are not one on top of the other. Please read:  `\node (a) at (0,0)` and `\node (b) at (1,1)`

Comment: @Torbiorn: that is a nice suggestion, thank you. The only problem is that I want to add colors to some of the nodes.

Comment: Use tab-completion, then you'll get the username right, and I'll be notified. I added an answer with a workaround for different colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom `to path`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ns/.style={
    to path={(\tikztostart.north) -- (\tikztotarget.south)\tikztonodes (\tikztotarget)}
}]
 \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {};
 \node[draw] (b) at (1,1) {};
 \node[draw] (c) at (2,-1){};
 \draw (a) to [ns] (b) to[ns] (c) to[ns] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is closer to my original question. All in all, in my original code was enough to substitute `\draw (a.north) -- (b.south);` with `\draw (a.north) to (b.south);` to have the style `every path/.style={parent anchor=north, child anchor=south}` performing what I meant. Yet, I do not understand the difference.

Comment: @brad For that you should better use `every to`

Answer (score 4):

You could use macros.  I should add that using one letter macro names is a bad idea.  Also, I'm surprised I didn't have to use `\pgfextra`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\n}[1]{(#1.north)}
\newcommand{\s}[1]{(#1.south)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (a) at (0,0) {};
 \node (b) at (0,1) {};
 \draw \n{a} -- \s{b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When the parser is not looking for something particular, say `(` or `[`, it will expand things as it walks on the code. Otherwise you have to pause the parser with `\pgfextra`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop to draw the lines. To specify different colours for the lines, you can have a third loop variable, and leave that empty where you want the default colour (black, unless you say otherwise).

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (a) at (0,0) {};
 \node (b) at (0,1) {};
 \node (c) at (0.2,0) {};
 \node (d) at (0.2,1) {};
 \node (e) at (0.4,0) {};
 \node (f) at (0.4,1) {};

\foreach \i/\j/\clr in {
   a/b/,
   c/d/red,
   e/f/}
  \draw [\clr] (\i.north) -- (\j.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, even if eventually I accepted the other one, because anyway this one is a nice workaround which can be useful in other occasions.